# In XAML, how can another element access the ScrollContentPresenter of a ListView?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Inside the `ItemTemplate` of a `ListView`, I'm able to access the `ActualWidth` property of the `ScrollContentPresenter` somewhere in the visual tree. In some scenarios this works well for me:

```
<ListView Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Width>
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}" />
                </Grid.Width>
                <!-- stuff goes here -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

However, I require some other XAML element to bind its width to the `ActualWidth` of MyListView's ScrollContentPresenter. How can that be accomplished, since there is no DependencyProperty on ListView corresponding to that ScrollContentPresenter?

Answer (score 0):

> How can that be accomplished, since there is no DependencyProperty on ListView corresponding to that ScrollContentPresenter?

Short answer: It can't.

Since the ScrollContentPresenter is "hidden" in the ControlTemplate that defines the visual tree of the ListView, no element outside the ListView itself will be able to bind to any property of this ScrollContentPresenter.

If other elements depend on the ScrollContentPresenter in some way you should reconsider your approach to whatever you are trying to do because binding to an element that is part of the ControlTemplate of a control is not possible.

And even if it actually was possible it would be a bad idea to do so since the details of how the ListView's ControlTemplate is defined is an implementation detail that may change in future versions and that no outside element should depend upon.